# how to get cell dimensions from rasterized ```SpatialPolygonsDataFrame```?

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

I have `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class in R, which I want to rasterize. I rasterize the the polygon using this code below:

```
> p <- shapefile('MadaGranary')
> p
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 100.1269, 100.5313, 5.793798, 6.446769  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : id 
value       :  1 
> crs(p) <- NULL

> # Define RasterLayer object
> r.raster <- raster(extent(p), res = 100)
> #rasterize
> p.r <- rasterize(p, r.raster)
> print(p.r)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 100.1269, 200.1269, -93.55323, 6.446769  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : NA, NA  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID id
  1  1
```

Unfortunately, this chunk of code has assigned cell dimensions to `dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)`, and its very important for me to get the actual values of `ncols and nrows`.

And when I `print p.r`, I need to get the values of `dimensions : (nrow, ncol, ncell)` in the console so that I will be able to save all attributes in order to use it another analysis later.
**attention**:The `resolution`output that I need to get should be real values representing `ncols and nrow` in the new raster, but not just `dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)` as shown in my code.

Can any one help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `nrow` and `ncol` then you do so (and not set the resolution, which expresses the size of each cell). Here is an example:

```
library(raster)
#Loading required package: sp
e <- extent(0,1,0,1)
r <- raster(e, nrow=100, ncol=100)
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : NA
```

Comment: The ```100``` is the cell resolution required in my analysis, but I don't know the ```nrow``` and ```ncol``` of the raster and the extent is extracted from extent from the ```SpatialPolygonsDataFrame```. So my question is, is there any way that I can determine the ```nrow``` and ```ncol``` of the raster  using the ```extent``` and ```cell size/resolution```?

Comment: "100" refer would refer to 100 degrees with these data. I assume that you want something else, perhaps 100 m2.  If so, you need to use an appropriate coordinate reference system. See https://rspatial.org/raster/spatial/6-crs.html